# browser freezes because of (too heavy?) JavaScript, canvas rendering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a draft website with canvas perspective grid rendered by Javascript (window.onload event), but while loading the site on any newest browser - browser freezes at least for a few seconds, even user interface not responsive. The script consists of 6 loops, totally over 200 iterations each drawing a line. How can I avoid the freezing? Set timeout after each iteration or after each loop? Could it be canvas issue?

[www.modwebsolutions.com/test](http://www.modwebsolutions.com/test) *(Will lock browser during rendering)*

Comment: Heh.. "view image" on the background canvas crashes my firefox.

Comment: For what it's worth, I only see this few seconds freeze in Opera over here.  Firefox, Safari, and Chrome render it instantly.

Comment: No lag here either except for a slight pause before the page draw.

Comment: For me it tooks well over few seconds, but I'm on XP now with quite outdated browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yeah, canvas is pretty unoptimized. Your canvas is also quite big ;)

Yes, you can delay further drawing, so the cpu can take care of browser input, thus reducing the freeze ;)

See: http://pastehtml.com/view/1e7dan3.html (it's not drawing everything, but you can get the point ;) )

Comment: Canvas uses the GPU in Firefox on Linux with at least some drivers (the nvidia binary drivers for sure) and in IE9 or Firefox 4 on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked quite well.

A thing you could do is, delegating the rendering to a web worker, so your "Main Thread" is free for user interactions

Answer (score 0):

JS runs in the same thread as the browser. So it's probably because the drawing is too cpu intensive. Yes, use timeouts/intervals to let the browser do some other stuff in between drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setTimeout() or setInterval() for drawing slow and to avoid browser freeze :)